# regex pattern to tokenize sentence while stripping end punctuation?

Tags: python, regex

I need to make a regex pattern that can tokenize a sentence with that also has punctuation tokenized separately, except for acronyms, contractions, and hyphens.

```
"This is a test sentence. I won't write this sentence. J. Smith lives in the U.S.A. and it is nice there."
```

should return as

```
["This" "is" "a" "test" "sentence" "." "I" "won't" "write" "this" "sentence" "." "J." "Smith" "lives" 
 "in" "the" "U.S.A." "and" "it" "is" "nice" "there" ."]
```

My code currently is:

```
tokens = re.findall(r'((\.\s)|(\S+))', sentence)
```

But this doesn't work correctly. It matches the period at the end of words as part of the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[^\s.]{2,}|(?:\w|\.)+` for tokenizing this particular example, but as Ryan mentions, without a natural language toolkit, this is an exercise in futility.

This regex enables two cases to be matched:

1. `[^\s.]{2,}` match 2 or more consecutive non-space, non-literal period characters
2. `(?:\w|\.)+` match one or more consecutive word characters or literal periods

Usage:

```
import re

s = """This is a test sentence. 
I won't write this sentence. J. Smith lives in the U.S.A.  and it is nice there.
"""

for token in re.findall(r"[^\s.]{2,}|(?:\w|\.)+", s):
    print(repr(token))
```

Output:

```
'This'
'is'
'a'
'test'
'sentence'
'.'
'I'
"won't"
'write'
'this'
'sentence'
'.'
'J.'
'Smith'
'lives'
'in'
'the'
'U.S.A.'
'and'
'it'
'is'
'nice'
'there'
'.'
```

Comment: Clever.  I like the `(?:\w?\.)+` for matching the single- or multi-letter abbreviations in one pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with regex.  There's no way to differentiate words containing punctuation ("J." in your example, or "Jr." would be one that's not a single character) where you want the punctuation as part of the token, from words followed by punctuation ("sentence." in your example) where you want the punctuation as its own token.

You need a natural language parsing library to get this to work as you've described the problem.

It may be possible to devise some heuristics like the length of the word and whether it's followed by a word with a capital letter, or whitelist common words that break the rules, but you're going to have issues making this work robustly.

Comment: OP looks like they might be content with just single-letters here, but this is the correct answer anyway.

Comment: Is there any way to do it with only single characters or without differentiating?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that works for what you have and can be used for similar sentences. Again, can not always be used if there's different variations.

```
([A-Z]\.\S*|\w+\'*\w*|[A-Z]\.|\.)
```